# Is freeing result sets necessary for mysqli persistent connections?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

According to [mysqli document](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php),

> Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically closed when their objects are destroyed. Explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional.

But is it also optional for mysqli persistent connections?

Comment: I would say it is not necessary either. But I would argue that it's a persistent connection which is not necessary in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is optional. A persistent connection is a connection that is not closed when the PHP process ends. When a new HTTP request is processed by PHP, it will reuse the same connection. Thus, you don't need to close the connection. Calling `mysqli_close()` has no effect on persistent connections.

As for freeing the result sets, mysqli will clean up any pending result sets regardless of the mode, when the script ends. **You never need to free the results manually.** The only reason to free result sets is when you have remaining unbuffered rows that you want to fetch and discard, and then execute another operation within the same script. This is the only time that using `mysqli_free_result()` is justified.

Mysqli will also [clean up the connection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.persistconns.php) by default (it can be disabled).

---

More importantly, persistent connections are often a nightmare to work with and if possible avoid it at all cost. The performance impact of connection is usually so tiny that most apps can live with opening a new connection for every request.

Comment: I think he is asking about freeing the resultsets. In theory you would need to do so, but given mysqli's implementation of a persistent connection, which by default calls mysql_change_user() that resets the connection state, I believe it frees the resultsets as well (that weren't freed already by setting to null in php)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Thanks for poiting this out. I misread the question and I changed the answer now. I am unable to verify this at the moment, but I believe that it happens independently of `mysql_change_user()`. I have some doubts about the accuracy of my answer, but I believe the point is correct.

Comment: Silly me, again I confused, this time resultsets allocated by the PHP process the OP is talking about, with mysql-side resources such as locks and transactions. So indeed, as any other php-allocated resource, those obviously get destroyed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Not totally silly. Unbuffered results MUST be fetched in full from the connection. Mysqlnd will always do that whenever the result object is destroyed. Because the result object cannot be persisted, mysqlnd will always fetch all rows and results sets.